# Getting hex representation of sha256 hash using SJCL

Tags: javascript, hex, sjcl

The [SJCL docs](http://cryptojs.altervista.org/hash/doc/doc_hash_stanford.html) provide the following code as an example for sha256:

```
var bitArray = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash("message");  
var digest_sha256 = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(bitArray);
```

The digest in that example being equal to a 64-character hex string, when I was expecting a 16-character hex string (256 bits = 16 hex characters). What am I missing? How can I get a 16-character digest of the hash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're misunderstanding something. 256 bits does **not** equal 16 hex digits.

Think of it this way: 256 bits is equal to 32 bytes (8 bits in a byte). A byte (8 bits) can encode 256 (2^8) different values. A single hexadecimal digit (base-16) can encode 16 different values. How many hex digits do you need if you want to encode the same number of values as a byte? **Two**; two hex digits can encode 256 different values (16^2). So, if we need two hex digits per byte, and 256 bits is equal to 32 bytes, then that means we need **64** hex digits to represent the information that can be stored in 256 bits.

The hex digest is fine. It's supposed to be 64 characters.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov: I liked your previous comment better. :)

Comment: Hah! I had this thought that if Google somehow placed this question high on the results page for my name, no one would ever hire me as a programmer again. For the record, my original comment was something along the lines of "Right. I confused 'a hex char has 16 possible values' with 'a hex char has 16 bits of information'". In my defense, I didn't sleep much the night before :)

Comment: how about Getting hex representation of sha512 hash??

Comment: @AminFarajzadeh: It would just be twice that - so, 128 hex digits.